# smartgwt grid summary issue

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, listgrid

I have a listgrid. I customize grid summary, I have the next options:

```
 setGroupByField("class_desc");

 setGroupStartOpen(GroupStartOpen.ALL);

 setShowGridSummary (true);

 setShowGroupSummary (true);

 setShowGroupSummaryInHeader (true);
```

But I can not make me show the division between categories, what am I doing wrong?

I'm sure the function name `setGroupByField` is the same as the datasource.

Answer (score 0):

please try with following link. Following is the link for the same requirement you are working on.

http://smartgwt.googlecode.com/svn-history/r901/trunk/samples/showcase/src/com/smartgwt/sample/showcase/client/grid/GridSummariesSample.java